# Js Progress stop after get() or load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, load

I have a click function will load page first and then continue the remaining process.

My problem is on the FIRST click, "Continue Here" will stop after `$.get()` function.

However, on the SECOND click it will work fine.

```
.click(){
  $.get(url, function(data){ content = data; } );

  // Continue here
  var x = content or etc...

}
```

Does anyone have idea about this? I am sure the problem is from the ajax loading, do I have a way to escape this? Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get is asynchronous, you must put your code inside the function

```
.click(){
  $.get(url, function(data){ 
    var content = data; 

    // Continue here
    var x = content; // or etc...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post much code, but I'm guessing the issue is due to your `get` call which is asynchronous. Therefore your variable `content` doesn't exist yet.

```
.click(){
  $.get(url, function(data){ 
        content = data; } 
 );

 // Continue here
 var x = content; 

 //but content isn't anything yet because GET has not yet returned from the server. 
 //By the time you click a second time, the data has finally round tripped.
```

You have to do X in your callback instead.

```
.click(){
   $.get(url, function(data){ 
        content = data; 
        var x = content;
    } 
);
```